# Replacing a electric receptacle in the middle of a series

Tags: electrical

I have an electric receptacle that looks like this.

[image: electrical socket with two sets of wires]

It's half-hot and in the middle of a series to one other socket.

UPDATE: The photo above is the one I had goofed up putting back together. Here's what it actually looks like (the red and black are on the same side as expected)

[image: sides of outlet]

And this is of course a plain receptacle.

[image: front/rear of basic receptacle]

I haven't been able to figure out (even with similar results) if it's possible to replace the top one with a bottom one. Another problem is determining which wire in each pair is from upstream or downstream.

Am I supposed to pigtail the pairs, along with a third wire that goes to this outlet? Mentally that doesn't seem like the right thing, but I couldn't really tell you why.

What would be the "correct" replacement receptacle for this usage? I'm having a hard time picking the right search terms.

Comment: Why are you replacing the outlet? Did it work as it's shown there?

Comment: Your replacement outlet is fine, but I'd really like to know why it was wired that way. That looks like original work from construction. Don't you think?

Comment: My only guess is that (if both tabs are removed) the installer just used the outlet as a wire nut to connect the reds for downstream use.

Comment: There's a definite crack in the plastic, so it seems like replacing this is a good idea. Also, it's hard to tell for sure, but it _looks_ like the tab is missing on the "black wire" side, so it looks like it's a split outlet, except that the bottom half would have never worked. Can you confirm if both outlets work/ever worked? Can you provide a square on shot of _both_ sides of the outlet?

Comment: A bit late here. @isherwood I'm replacing it simply because the contacts are loose, stuff doesn't stay stuck in.

Comment: @FreeMan It seems I attached the wrong photo of a mistake I had made when putting the outlet back together. Black and red are definitely on the same side, pull tab broken, with white and a pull tab in place. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One weird thing to my eyes is that white and red are on the same side.

Yeah, that's broke-a-doodle.  Either someone wildly miswired other points in the circuit, or this tripped the breaker instantly when someone threw the switch, or it "burned out" one of the backstab connections which happens all the time.

> Another problem is determining which wire in each pair is from upstream or downstream.

Doesn't matter. Work it out; regardless of what the answer is, the wiring will be identical.   So it is not a thing you need to know.

> Am I supposed to pigtail the pairs, along with a third wire that goes to this outlet? Mentally that doesn't seem like the right thing, but I couldn't really tell you why.

It literally does not matter.  You can pigtail, or you can use a receptacle which allows an onboard splice.   Your call, you can do it any way which suits you.

For instance, I usually pigtail because I'm attaching quad outlets on metal boxes in stress positions like on ceilings or under desks. Much easier to assemble the domed covers and pigtails on an ergonomic bench!

The only exception is certain applications where pigtailing is required. Safety ground, obviously.  Or neutral in certain types of circuits.

> What would be the "correct" replacement receptacle for this usage?

Not the 50 cent cheapie in your photo. If you graduate to the $2.50 spec-grade outlets, most of them have a feature called "screw-and-clamp" where each screw also functions as a plate clamp, that can grab up to 2 wires.  Easy peasy.

Comment: I goofed, the photo I had attached is when I had made a mistake, new photos attached with correct wiring. Thank you for the rest, I appreciate breaking down the answer. It sounds like the answer is either pigtail each pair under the same screw, or buy a plate-and-clamp outlet. Having a hard time searching for it on Home Depot, but I'll take a look in store, hopefully they're actually $2.50

Answer (score 3):

This example should trip the breaker the second it is turned on.

Someone screwed up and stabbed the reds on the wrong side. They probably broke the tab to get half the receptacle to work and not trip the breaker, or pulled the red feeder at the switch.

When the new receptacle is installed don’t use the backstabs--they are the leading cause of failure. Pigtail is the correct method, or use more expensive outlets which have a plate at the screw and allow 2 wires per screw.

The tab should be broken on the black/red or "hot" side. The tab should not be broken on the white side.

Normally the red is a switched hot and the black is a always hot. Since this was mis-wired it would never work with both receptacles.

Comment: Or, the red carries on elsewhere as isherwood mentioned in a comment on the OP and a wire nut on the reds, bypassing the outlet completely, will give the OP 2 working receptacles here now.

Comment: @freeman Even if used to carry on it would be a code violation as it is a hot  conductor on a neutral lug. The only color wires allowed on that lug are white and gray.  My belief is who ever wired it made a mistake notice the broken tab on the hot side? This is why I stated it probably tripped the breaker and the tab was then removed or the red from the switch. I can’t believe any electrician would do this or leave it. I have seen DIY like this and it was not caught on inspection, but probably no inspection/ no permit.

Comment: @EdBeal I goofed! The original photo was of when I made mistakes months ago. I added new ones, which have the black and red on the correct side. Thanks for the rest. So, it looks like the answer is either 1) pigtail the two and shove it under the same screw, or 2) buy a plate and clamp outlet.

Comment: Thanks, @EdBeal. I stand corrected.